# Ruby to_s a special method?

Tags: ruby, string, class, metaprogramming

I'm working on [Ruby Koans about_to_str.rb](https://github.com/javierjulio/ruby-koans-completed/blob/master/about_to_str.rb). I've gotten it to work but some code I don't understand. I'm confused why the `CanNotBeTreatedAsString` classes `to_s` produces different results than the `CanBeTreatedAsString` `to_s`

Both tests `test_to_str_allows_objects_to_be_treated_as_strings` & `test_normally_objects_cannot_be_used_where_strings_are_expected`check for a file that exists by doing the same thing yet one raises an error while the other doesn't.

Can someone offer a high-level overview of the concept I'm unaware of here?

```
  class CanNotBeTreatedAsString
    def to_s
      "non-string-like"
    end
  end

  def test_to_s_returns_a_string_representation
    not_like_a_string = CanNotBeTreatedAsString.new
    assert_equal "non-string-like", not_like_a_string.to_s
  end

  def test_normally_objects_cannot_be_used_where_strings_are_expected
    assert_raise(TypeError) do
      File.exist?(CanNotBeTreatedAsString.new)
    end
  end


  class CanBeTreatedAsString
    def to_s
      "string-like"
    end

    def to_str
      to_s
    end
  end

  def test_to_str_also_returns_a_string_representation
    like_a_string = CanBeTreatedAsString.new
    assert_equal "string-like", like_a_string.to_str
  end

  def test_to_str_allows_objects_to_be_treated_as_strings
    assert_equal false, File.exist?(CanBeTreatedAsString.new)
  end
```

Comment: It seems to me that using `to_str` "cleanes" the `to_s` and allows it to be interpreted as a **String.literal**

Comment: `to_s` belongs to `Object` and consequently it is implemented by all Ruby objects but `to_str` is a method of class `String`. In order to work similar to the `String` class, the class `CanBeTreatedAsString` have to implement it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where *exactly* does `to_s` "produce different results"?

Comment: Both tests are testing different classes and in both classes the `to_s` are defined to return different strings. Why are you surprised about the fact that they return different results?

Comment: @spickermann I phrased it poorly. Why do both tests hit the `to_s` method and one throws an error while the other doesn't.

Comment: At least I think when I call `.new` it calls `to_s` on the first class, on the second class I think when I call `.new` it calls `to_str` which then calls `to_s`, I think.